# Get DOT file from a graph when using DiagrammeR

Tags: r, graph, dotfiles, diagrammer

It looks like DiagrammeR has changed their `create_nodes` and `create_edges` functions than it looks on the doc. 
Also the `$dot_code` attribute is not there anymore. I can't find the replacement for this.

Here is the example code that they had on the doc, but it is not working. 
The following example is found in their official [DiagrammeR web](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphs.html).

```
###
# Create a graph with both nodes and edges
# defined, and, add some default attributes
# for nodes and edges
###

library(DiagrammeR)

# Create a node data frame
nodes <-
  create_nodes(nodes = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
               label = FALSE,
               type = "lower",
               style = "filled",
               color = "aqua",
               shape = c("circle", "circle",
                         "rectangle", "rectangle"),
               data = c(3.5, 2.6, 9.4, 2.7))

edges <-
  create_edges(from = c("a", "b", "c"),
               to = c("d", "c", "a"),
               rel = "leading_to")


graph <-
  create_graph(nodes_df = nodes,
               edges_df = edges,
               node_attrs = "fontname = Helvetica",
               edge_attrs = c("color = blue",
                              "arrowsize = 2"))

graph
#> $nodes_df
#>   nodes label  type  style color     shape data
#> 1     a       lower filled  aqua    circle  3.5
#> 2     b       lower filled  aqua    circle  2.6
#> 3     c       lower filled  aqua rectangle  9.4
#> 4     d       lower filled  aqua rectangle  2.7
#>
#> $edges_df
#>   from to        rel
#> 1    a  d leading_to
#> 2    b  c leading_to
#> 3    c  a leading_to
#>
#> $graph_attrs
#> [1] NULL
#>
#> $node_attrs
#> [1] "fontname = Helvetica"
#>
#> $edge_attrs
#> [1] "color = blue"  "arrowsize = 2"
#>
#> $directed
#> [1] TRUE
#>
#> $dot_code
#> [1] "digraph {\n\ngraph [rankdir = LR]\n\nnode [fontnam...
#>
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "dgr_graph"

# View the graph in the RStudio Viewer
render_graph(graph)
```

Answer (score 0):

look into the help of the DiagrammeR package, the website is indeed not up-to-date.
Look at the function create_graph() in the help that shows how the syntax changed.

something like this should do the same:

```
    ###

library(DiagrammeR)

# Create a node data frame (ndf) where the labels
# are equivalent to the node ID values (this is not
# recommended); the `label` and `type` node
# attributes will always be a `character` class
# whereas `id` will always be an `integer`
nodes <-
  create_node_df(
    n         = 4,
    type      = "lower", 
    label     = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
    style     = "filled",
    fillcolor = "blue",
    shape     = c("circle", "circle",
                  "rectangle", "rectangle"),
    data      = c(3.5, 2.6, 9.4, 2.7))

# Create an edf with additional edge
# attributes (where their classes will
# be inferred from the input vectors)
edges <-
  create_edge_df(
    from = c(1, 2, 3),
    to   = c(4, 3, 1),
    rel  = "leading_to")

# With `create_graph()` we can
# simply create an empty graph (and
# add in nodes and edges later
# with other functions)
graph <-
  create_graph(
    nodes_df  = nodes,
    edges_df  = edges)     %>%
  set_edge_attrs(
    edge_attr = color,
    values    = "green")   %>%
  set_edge_attrs(
    edge_attr = arrowsize,
    values    = 2)         %>%
  set_node_attrs(
    node_attr = fontname,
    values    = "Helvetica")

graph

render_graph(graph)
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Bad News

For anyone viewing this *zombie thread*, as of this posting, the information posted on  Rich Iannone's documentation page for DiagrammeR is **still out of date**: http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graph_creation.html.

### The Good News

However, the vignettes for the Diagrammer package contain updated information. As shown in the package vignette named [Creating Simple Graphs from NDFs/EDFs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiagrammeR/vignettes/simple-graphs-ndfs-edfs.html), you can view and export `GraphViz` *dot code* with a function named `generate_dot()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for the close read of `DiagrammeR` vignette, and how it applies to this question.